# Why does (probe-file #P"/") return nil?

Tags: common-lisp, ecl

This seems like it could be a bug in ECL's implementation -- or due to some detail in the standard:

```
    > (probe-file #P"/usr")

    #P"/usr/"
    > (probe-file #P"/usr/")

    #P"/usr/"
    > (probe-file #P"/")

    NIL
    > (probe-file #P"//")

    NIL
```

One more case:

```
    > (probe-file #P"/.")

    #P"/"
```

Update, FWIW, SBCL does what I expect:

```
    * (probe-file #P"/")

    #P"/"
```

Comment: The difference in behavior between `(probe-file "/")` and `(probe-file "/usr/")` is probably an implementation bug.

Comment: which platform?

Comment: The Common Lisp standard says almost nothing about actual pathnames and actual filesystems. The behavior here is implementation specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a commit message from the fix I'm testing right now (hope this answers the question – it was a bug indeed):

> unixfsys: remove coerce_to_posix_filename
>
> This was a workaround around bugs in cygwin and mingw (which are
>   already fixed), when the directory name ended with '/'. This fix
>   introduced extra bug with probe-file called on the root directory (it
>   returned nil on all platforms).
>
> Original comment:
>
> This converts a pathname designator into a namestring, with the
>   particularity that directories do not end with a slash '/', because
>   this is not supported on all POSIX platforms (most notably Windows).
>
> Bug reference:
>
> https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/patches/34/
>
> Fixes #351.